# C# Concurrency: Writing on different object properties

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I have the following situation: I have a C# dictionary which has an int as key (unique ID) and a custom class as value e.g. `Dictionary<int, CustomClass>` (It's not a `ConcurrentDictionary`). Is it thread safe / are there any race conditions if I spawn multiple threads which all set data on different class properties over the whole dictionary? All *add* operations on the dictionary have been done before the threads set the data.

**Update with code (to clear things a little bit):**

```
class Foo {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

// Initialized with 100 entries - Keys: 0 to 99
Dictionary<int, Foo> dict = new Dictionary<int, Foo>();

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for(int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++) {
        dict[i].Prop1 = "whatever";
    }
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for(int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++) {
        dict[i].Prop2 = "whatever";
    }
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    for(int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++) {
        dict[i].Prop3 = "whatever";
    }
}));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Consider using `lock` statement to make your operations thread safe.

Comment: Would any of the threads be accessing the same object/value or property of that object? Would any of those operations rely on reading the property values, or just setting them?

Comment: It will be helpful to give more details on what exactly you plan to do with the objects. There could be race conditions that affect the values of the properties if you read and write them from different threads. The simplest solution would be to have an `object` for each value, to `lock` when interacting with the object, but that could be overkill.

Comment: Each threads writes data to different properties of the custom class but on all items of the dictionary. So there aren't two threads which write data into the same property, but there are at least two threads which write data into different properties on the same object.

Comment: I wouldn't count on having no code changes in the future that mess things up so I would use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and also make the whole reading/writing threadsafe. I mean, why not do it the good way? Time saving now vs unpredictable behavior in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A race condition occurs when 2 or more blocks of code access to the same resource changing its state, and the changing itself and/or the behaviour of these blocks depend on a specific order of execution of the blocks themeselves.

Therefore, if there aren't any dependencies between your threads about their execution on the same resource then you can neglect if they access simultaneously to it.

While if it is important that each of them makes a "visible" change on the property that it is accessing and there are some dependencies between the properties about their values, for example one property, when assigned, affects the value of some one other, then, you have to synchronize the access to that property.

Answer (score -2):

If different threads are editing different properties of the same object, then yes it is safe. You will have a race condition if you try to edit the same property on the same object from multiple threads.

This is assuming that the properties are not referencing shared state, which is what your code example shows.

Comment: Different properties could still be using shared state of some sort, so you can't actually know that it's safe given the information provided.

Comment: The question shows the code, there's no shared state... but added a note anyway. Not sure what the downvotes are for, either people are confused or they just don't know.

Comment: You answered before the code was shown.  Had you only answered *after* the code was shown, then that would be different.